# what is the proper package selection for using dc.js charting library with meteor

Tags: meteor, dc.js

I'm trying to put together a meteor app, which uses dc.js charting library.
I have added chrts:dc package. My meteor list is:

```
autopublish           1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Publish the entire database to all clients
blaze-html-templates  1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
charts:dc             1.7.4  Multi-Dimensional charts built to work natively with crossfilter rendered with d3.js (dc.js)
ecmascript            0.1.6* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
ejson                 1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
es5-shim              4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
insecure              1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
jquery                1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-base           1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience     1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                 1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
session               1.1.1  Session variable
standard-minifiers    1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker               1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
```

When I run the app, I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined   chart.js:8743

Cannot read property 'length' of null              pfafman_crossfilter.js:560
```

Perhaps, anyone in the meteor community is using dc.js, and could give me a clear direction as to what packages should be added to make meteor work with dc.js

Answer (score 1):

What I have done to solve this, was to load the actual original libraries (d3.js and crossfilter.js) instead of the smart package surrogaes. Just simply placed both libraries under app/client/lib, and this started to work together just fine.